# Odoo - Modify the journal items in an invoice only for a specific tax

Tags: python, odoo

I am new to Odoo (Python ) that is why I am struggling to do this task, I hope you can shred light on it. Thanks in advance, let me explain ;):

Some products are taxed with a special tax called *REBU (sales)*. The value of this tax depends on the purchase cost and the sales price as follows, example:

item 1 is purchased in REBU by: 100e.

item 1 is sold in REBU for 300e.

journal items must be:

```
base excempt = 100e = purchase cost.
base taxed: ( sale price - purchase cost ) / 1.21 = (300-100)/1.21 = 165.289e
tax: ( sale price - purchase cost ) - base taxed = ( 300 - 100 ) - 165.289 = 34.711
```

It is simple math but it is difficult to modify the JOURNAL ITEMS of the invoice accordingly. note: the invoice lines are correct, no need to bne modifed, only journal items.

I attach screenshots of how both look like now.
[image: Invoice lines - correct]
[image: Journal lines - what I want to modify]

My thinking:
I use a REBU ( sales ) tax at 0% so the sales order and invoice lines are correct ( my client must not know how much taxes I pay for that sale, otherwise he could figure out my purchase cost ).

Then when a product is invoiced with this REBU ( sales ) tax, in the journal items of this invoice we should split the "base" into two bases as I previously explained, and the tax as explained as well.
*we could apply one tax called "excempt" at 0% to the excempt base and another tax called "REBU" at 21% for the taxed base so all math is good*

I tried this, my code so far:
1º There is a condition to know if it is REBU or not.
2º The purchase cost is in: "lot.x_serial_purchase_precio"
3º We try to apply two taxes to the new two bases in journal lines.

note: it is not working good.

code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J4JGWd1wSGecMwupsQ8dIIXZNmDnAJlj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107541502685755287748&rtpof=true&sd=true

I tried to split the base into two bases, one to be taxed by 21%, and another to be excempt of any tax.

Comment: Very interesting question for me as Odoo developer, but probably to complex to answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've tried it out with Odoo 16 very fast. It's nearly possible. You need a tax with python code computation. And that's the pitfall or the part you need to code something yourself. Right now new fields are not supported in the computation code. So you have to find a way to add new fields there.

But everything else is working. An example for such a tax is:
[image]

As you can see i've used the field `quantity` here instead of a purchase price field. But it's only for demonstration.
And the Distribution settings will lead to 0 taxes on the invoice, which was one of your requirements. (used accounts have to changed to you local ones ofcourse)

And now an example for an invoice (with quantity as "purchase price").

[image]

And the journal items:

[image]

Comment: Hello, mmm it is not a final solution because I wonder how it is gonna affect the journal lines but it is absolutely something to think about it. I may find a solution bc of your answer. if so, I will post it here. thanks *one small question, if I wanted to placed the result of the code ( example: 34,71$ ) on the base line, how could I?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "on the base line"? And what's the problem with the tax journal items? Do you need another tax on top of it (vat?), im not sure if adding a second tax would work, but it could, because the first (REBU) ends up to create "zero" taxes so the base amount is not touched.